# Laravel: Image not loading

Tags: php, image, laravel

I am trying to load an image in Laravel. The image is loading in a `header.blade.php` file. It is working fine on other pages but when it comes to `localhost:8000/edit/id`, It just doesn't work. I am loading Image like this:

```
<a href="{!! URL::to('/') !!}">
   <img src="images/logo.png" />
</a>
```

My Route:

```
Route::get('edit/{id}', array('uses' => 'HomeController@edit'));
```

My Controller:

```
 public function edit($id) {
    $reg = Register::find($id);
    $user = User::where('email', Session::get('email'))->first();
    if ($reg->user_id == $user->id) {
        return View::make('edit')
                        ->with('id', $id);
    } else {
        return Redirect::to('dashboard')->with('wrong', 'Sorry! Something Went Wrong!');
    }
}
```

My image directory: `public/images/logo.png`

It is working fine on other pages like `localhost:8000/about` but it doesn't work on `localhost/edit/2`, any help?

Comment: try <img src="/images/logo.png" />

Comment: Holy God! I spent last half an hour figuring it out, and just added a slash, like you said, and its working, Thanks!

Comment: Awesome! I've added my answer as an actual answer aswel. Feel free to mark it if it helped

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that when you are on your url, it is not looking for the image in the root folder of your application, but in the current location.

So when you are visiting localhost/edit/2, it is looking for the image in localhost/edit, instead of in localhost.

Try changing your code by adding a slash in the beginning of the image

```
<a href="{!! URL::to('/') !!}">
   <img src="images/logo.png" />
</a>
```

to

```
<a href="{!! URL::to('/') !!}">
   <img src="/images/logo.png" />
</a>
```

Additionally, you should actually try the laravel way, like this:

```
{{ HTML::image('images/logo.png', 'logo') }}
```

Answer (score 3):

try

```
{{ HTML::image('images/logo.png', 'logo') }}
```

output will be like

```
<img src="http://your.url/images/logo.png" alt="logo">
```

also you can check image path using inspect element in browser

Comment: You can also do `<img src="<?= asset('images/logo.png') ?>" alt="logo">`

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src="public/storage/cover_images/image_name.format"  class="img-resposive">
```

it will load your picture otherwise check the path to image and previlages of the folders you can load image only from a public path due to security reasons